# assert menu.__str__() == "" AssertionError

Tags: python, class

I get assertion error when i try to assert "" (empty string) into str function. Could anyone enlighten me as of why that happens. Totally clueless here. I know the str function needs to return a string but as far as i know it is returning a string when i run:

The error comes when i run:

```
menu = Menu() 
assert menu.str() == ""
```

here is my code:

```
    class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = counter
        my_list = []
        self.my_list = my_list
        

    def __str__(self):
        for element in self.a_list:
            if element:
                return "\n".join(f"{counter}. {element}" for counter, 
                element in enumerate(self.my_list, 1)) 
            print()
```

Comment: `x.str()` is not the same as `str(x)`, which calls `x.__str__()`

Comment: I think you wanted `assert str(menu)==""`, but even that isn't valid.  If your object is empty, your `__str__` function returns None, not an empty string.  Perhaps `assert not menu.str()` would be better.

Comment: Also, you should debug your code. What happens when you actually `print(repr(menu.str()))`? Is it an empty string?

Comment: Hmm it returns Attribute Error

Comment: What is the full attribute error message? Does it say "has no attribute 'str'"? You don't have a `str` method in your example and your `assert menu.str() == "" ` should have failed the same way.

Comment: The way `__str__` is implemented, you return a string containing all elements if at least one element is not empty, otherwise you return `None`. You could add `return ""` to the bottom of the function to fix the `None`.

Comment: I believe after removing (for element in self.a_list:  if element:) inside the __str__ function it fixed the problem. Is it because it does not check for an element in the list?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ . You [are expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to try to solve the problem yourself first - so what happened when you tried to figure out what is going on? How about when you tried to *read and understand* the error message? How about when you tried *checking the actual value*?

Comment: "Hmm it returns Attribute Error" Right, because like the *first* comment told you, you **cannot** use `x.str()` to mean the same thing as `str(x)`. Also, notice that an `AttributeError` **is not** "assertion error" like you initially described the problem. It is only possible to fix code if you actually *read* and *pay attention to* what the computer tells you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the declaration is `def __str__(self):` you need to call it like

```
assert menu.__str__() == ""
```

Or using `str` method

```
assert str(menu) == ""
```

---

Also you have a for loop, that includes another loop on the same `a_list`. A good implementation is

```
# with classic for loop syntax
def __str__(self):
    result = ""
    for counter, element in enumerate(self.a_list, 1):
        result += f"{counter}. {element}\n"
    return result


# with generator syntax
def __str__(self):
    return "\n".join(f"{c}. {elem}" for c, elem in enumerate(self.a_list, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `__str__()` function does not return a string if nothing is added to the object before the assertion. An assertion error would be generated even if the function was called correctly.